# AsyncTask.get() in Activity.onCreate makes it take too much time to load and sometimes it crashes

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

When I start this activity, it takes too much time to load and sometimes my app crashes. I want to know if there is anything I can do so the activity will no start until the main activity is fully loaded in the previous activity or something like this so my activity will load without problems or crushes.

AdvertisingActivity.java

```
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.Animatable2Compat;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.DataSource;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gif.GifDrawable;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestListener;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class AdvertisingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imageView;
    ImageView imageButton;
    String ImageClick = "";
    String ImageLink = "";
    private TextView Countdowner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.advertising);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.Advertisings);
        imageButton = findViewById(R.id.closebuttons);
        imageButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Countdowner = findViewById(R.id.Countdowns);
        final ParseJson parsejson = new ParseJson();
        try {
            parsejson.execute().get();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ImageLink = parsejson.getHouseAdsImage();
        ImageClick = parsejson.getHouseAdsClick();
        boolean ifGif = parsejson.getGIF();


        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(parsejson.getHouseAdsClick()));
                AdvertisingActivity.this.startActivity(browserIntent);
            }
        });


        if (ifGif == true) {
            Glide.with(this).asGif().load(parsejson.getHouseAdsImage()).listener(new RequestListener<GifDrawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<GifDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    finish();
                    Toast.makeText(AdvertisingActivity.this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(GifDrawable resource, Object model, Target<GifDrawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    resource.setLoopCount(1);
                    resource.registerAnimationCallback(new Animatable2Compat.AnimationCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Drawable drawable) {
                            Glide.with(AdvertisingActivity.this).load(parsejson.getAfterGif()).into(imageView);
                            Toast.makeText(AdvertisingActivity.this, "GIF stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                    new CountDownTimer(13000, 1000) {

                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                            Countdowner.setText("You can close ad after: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                        }

                        public void onFinish() {
                            imageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Countdowner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }.start();
                    Toast.makeText(AdvertisingActivity.this, "Success to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    return false;
                }
            }).into(imageView);

        } else {
            Glide.with(AdvertisingActivity.this).load(parsejson.getAfterGif()).into(imageView);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When it crashes, what is in the logs? Is there an exception?

Comment: @KevinHooke it takes too much time to load data from my Host

Comment: `AsyncTask` has been deprecated for a couple of years. Please consider using something else: ordinary threads, an `Executor` from `Executors`, RxJava, Kotlin coroutines, etc.

Comment: Is this for a class? If not, whatever tutorial you are using is probably very outdated. Android is usually done in Kotlin these days

Comment: @Novaterata yes for a class. I'm still using Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're waiting synchronously on the main thread for your `AsyncTask` to finish:

```java
parsejson.execute().get();
```

You should basically never be calling `AsyncTask.get()` on the main thread: it will block the thread until it finishes, which defeats the point of an AsyncTask, which is to *not* block the main thread.

Instead, you should do whatever you're waiting for in [`AsyncTask.onPostExecute`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#onPostExecute(Result)).

Comment: am I going to move what is written in doInBackground to onPostExecute ?

Comment: @JosephLanga No, `onPostExecute` should be the things you're currently doing on the UI thread that depend on what's in `doInBackground` having been completed.

Comment: @JosephLanga in case it's not clear, 'async/asynchronous' means that the code will run 'in the background' usually using a separate processor thread; although, interlacing on the same thread is sometimes used. So there is the phase where you submit the task then the phase where you wait for it to complete if you need the result (optional, you could just let it run ignoring the result, i.e. fire-and-forget).

Comment: @Novaterata I got it. Thank you so much. I added ProgressDialog to my code so when a user opens the activity the progress dialog appears until async is completed then the progress dialog disappears.