# Why Async Task Freezes my UI till the Image Loads

Tags: android, android-asynctask, freeze

This code in background freezes my ui till the image loads in image holder from chat adapter(or we can say that when this background task completes then image loads in image holder)

```
inner class loadContacts(val applicat: Application) : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>(){
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Boolean {

            var firebaseUser=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!
            val contentResolver = applicat.contentResolver
            val contacts = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null)

            while (contacts?.moveToNext() == true) {
                val name = contacts.getString(contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME))
                val phoneNumber = contacts.getString(contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))
                var i=0
                var phone_num:String=""
                while(i!=phoneNumber.length){
                    if(phoneNumber[i]>='0'&&phoneNumber[i]<='9'){
                        phone_num=phone_num+phoneNumber[i]
                    }
                    i++
                }

                val ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users")
                ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object :ValueEventListener{
                    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                        for(snapshot in snapshot.children){
                            val num=snapshot.child("number").value.toString()
                            val userid=snapshot.child("uid").value.toString()
                            val url=snapshot.child("profile_photo").value.toString()
                            if(userid!=firebaseUser.uid && phone_num==num){
                                var imagepath=""
                                if(url!=""){
                                    val photo=GetImageFromUrl().execute(url).get()
                                    imagepath=saveToInternalStorage(photo,userid).execute().get()
                                }
                                ContactViewModel(applicat).inserContact(ContactEntity(name,phone_num,imagepath,userid))
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                        TODO("Not yet implemented")
                    }

                })

            }
            contacts!!.close()
            return true
        }
    }




inner class saveToInternalStorage:AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{
        var path:String?=null
        var user:String?=null
        var bitmapImage:Bitmap?=null
        constructor(bitmapImage: Bitmap, user: String) : super() {
            this.user=user
            this.bitmapImage=bitmapImage
        }

        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): String {
            val directory: File = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "/Flow/Medias/Contacts Images")
            if(directory.exists()){
                path=user+".jpg"
                var fos: FileOutputStream =
                    FileOutputStream(File(directory, path))
                try {
                    bitmapImage!!.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, fos)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                } finally {
                    try {
                        fos.close()
                    } catch (e: IOException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                directory.mkdirs()
                if (directory.isDirectory) {
                    path=user+".jpg"
                    val fos =
                        FileOutputStream(File(directory, path))
                    try {
                        bitmapImage!!.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, fos)
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            fos.close()
                        } catch (e: IOException) {
                            e.printStackTrace()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return path!!
        }

    }



class GetImageFromUrl() : AsyncTask<String?, Void?, Bitmap>() {
    var bmp:Bitmap?=null
    override fun doInBackground(vararg url: String?): Bitmap {
        val stringUrl = url[0]
        bmp= null
        val inputStream: InputStream
        try {
            inputStream = URL(stringUrl).openStream()
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return bmp!!
    }
}
```

This code in background freezes my ui till the image loads in image holder from chat adapter(or we can say that when this background task completes then image loads in image holder)

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: `AsyncTask` is deprecated. Please consider using something else (plain threads, `Executor`, RxJava, Kotlin coroutines, etc.). Also, there are excellent image-loading libraries already written, such as Glide and Picasso -- you should consider using one. Beyond that, calling `get()` on an `AsyncTask`, as you are doing here, means that you should not have written it as an `AsyncTask` in the first place.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/68752077/208273

Comment: Basically, calling `get()` on an `AsyncTask` says "do the work, but do not do it asynchronously". It would be simpler to just not have the `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Calling get is also the problem.  You would execute the task, and not get it.  If you ever use get on an AsyncTask, you're almost certainly wrong.

Comment: Thank you Everyone I got my answer.
This is all because of get()